# Android Detekt Build failed

Tags: android, kotlin, build, detekt

I tried to generate code report using detekt and when execute the below command in terminal

**gradle detekt**

it showing build failed with below message.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:detekt'.
> Build failed with 395 weighted issues.
```

Comment: You have **395 issues** you need to resolve, try running it using android studio and you will find the issues like [this](https://imgur.com/NrDbVsp)

Comment: All issues should be printed explicitely in your log. Solve them or ignore them. At the beginning you could put them into a detekt-baseline file. You can configure it and run `./gradlew detektBaseline`, after that detekt will ignore those existing issues.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said in the comments, this means you have 395 issues in your code (kind of like lint warnings).

Detekt has a `maxissues:` property that determines whether or not to fail the build if your issues surpass the allowed number of `maxissues`.  What I did was search the whole project for `maxissues`, which will take you to your `detekt-config.yml` or `default-detekt-config.yml`.  There, you can change your `maxissues` to whatever you want.

In our old code base, we had 900 some issues, so I changed mine from `maxissues:0` to  `masissues:1000`.  As we clean up the code, I hope to bring that number down.